# Bootstrap static footer using navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I use the following code to create a footer using `Bootstrap`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <span class="navbar-brand">Ok Bye</span>
        </div>

        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">company &copy; 2017</p>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I want a static `footer` at the bottom of the page, not one that is visible all the time in the `viewport`. What is the `Bootstrap` way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you are missing something. nav is used for navigation not for footer. Please correct your code properly. this might can help: 
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 2):

The static footer has an implementation in Bootstrap. You don't need to use `<nav>`

**CSS:**

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</footer>
```